# Many errors from mixing <cstdlib> function calls with <string> functions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that counts the number of vowels and consonants in a word given by the user. I used  for functions like strlen() to get the length of my user input array for iteration. I also used bits/stdc++.h, so I could call the count() function for any occurrence of a vowel in the user input.

To check for the occurrences of vowels, I tried a couple functions starting from count, to find_first_of, to find(), to count() again. My first errors started by saying that it doesn't recognize the call to strlen(). I checked to make sure that I included the right package to use strlen(), but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I'm running this program on my MacBook Pro with High Sierra.

```
  #include <iostream>//std::cout
  #include <string>//std::string
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <set>// std::size_t
  #include "/Users/Desktop/stdc++.h"

  using namespace std;

  int main(){
      string input = "hello";
      cout << " The input is " << input << endl;
      std::size_t vowelsFound = 0;

      /*cout << " Enter a word, and we will count the vowels and    consonants: ";
      cin >> input;
      cout << " You entered " << input << endl;*/

      char cons[] =    {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z'};

      char vows[] = {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};

      std::size_t n = strlen(input);
      std::size_t v = strlen(vows);

      for(int i = 0; i < v; i++){
          if(count(input,input + n,vows[i]) != 0){
              vowelsFound += count(input,input + n, vows[i]);//count of vowels in vows[] encountered in input
              cout << " The vowel(s) found is " << vowelsFound << endl;
    }
          else{
              cout << " The vowel " << vows[i] << " is not found in input " << endl;
    }
}

  cout << " The amount of vowels found is " << vowelsFound << endl;
  cout << " The expected amount of vowels found is 2 " << endl;
}
```

I hardcoded the phrase "hello" for input, so when all is said and done the vowel count should be 2.

Comment: `strlen(input)`This only works with 0-terminated strings, which you DON'T have. Use  a `vector<char>` and get its size instead. There are probably other issues as well, so not an answer at this stage.

Comment: I'm also not sure when I should be using std::size_t. I initially just defined n and v as type int, and thought that would suffice. I understand that std::size_t is for unsigned integers, but my integers will never be negative, so I'm not sure why it matters that I use std::size_t at all. I'm really not sure what its purpose is to begin with. I've never seen that format for defining a type.

Comment: Really the simplest thing is to forget about char arrays and use std::string throughout. They are the safest and most flexible and you'll only have one thing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code:

1. I don't know what is in the `"/Users/richardlopez/Desktop/stdc++.h"` include but it is unlikely that it is a good thing to include. You probably want `#include <cstring>` to get `strlen`
2. you can't use `strlen` on a `std::string`, it only works on null terminated character arrays. You should just use `input.size()` instead.
3. you also shouldn't use `strlen` on `vows` as although it is a character array so will compile it is not null terminated so the return value of `strlen` is undefined. You can use `sizeof(vows)` or just make `vows` a `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead.
4. `count(input,input + n,vows[i])` is not correct. `input + n` doesn't compile. What you presumably meant is `count(input.begin(),input.end(),vows[i])`

Correcting the above issues and using modern c++ results in the simpilifed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string input = "hello";
  std::cout << " The input is " << input << "\n";
  std::size_t vowelsFound = 0;

  std::string cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
  std::string vows = "aeiou";

  for ( auto v : vows )
  {
      size_t c = std::count(input.begin(), input.end(), v);
      if ( c != 0 )
      {
          vowelsFound += c;
          std::cout << "found " << c << " " << v << "\n";
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << " The vowel " << v << " is not found in input\n";              
      }
  }

  std::cout << " The amount of vowels found is " << vowelsFound << "\n";
  std::cout << " The expected amount of vowels found is 2\n";
}
```

If all you need is the total number of vowels you can just use:

```
std::cout << " The amount of vowels found is " << std::count_if( input.begin(), input.end(), [&](char c)
  {
    return vows.find(c) != std::string::npos;
  }) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues, on top of "/Users/richardlopez/Desktop/stdc++.h" . If you need a specific function, look the reference and include the appropriate official C++ header for the functionality.

First `strlen` is for 0-terminated `char*`. It doesn't work on `input`. For that, just use:

```
auto n = input.size();
```

Then the same for `vows`:

```
std::vector<char> vows{'a','e','i','o','u','y'};
auto v = vows.size();
```

Then `count` is also different:

```
std::count(std::begin(input) ,std::end(input), vows[i])
```

If you have C++17, do:

```
if(auto count = std::count(std::begin(input), std::end(input), vows[i]); count > 0)
{
    vowelsFound += count;
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Simply `vowelsFound += std::count(std::begin(input), std::end(input), vows[i]);`

Comment: OP had some debugging info to add in the condition that I didn't reproduce (I should have). That would be the proper refactoring indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the partition algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string input = "hello";
    std::cout << " The input is " << input << std::endl;

    std::vector<char> vows = {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};
    auto it_vows_end = std::partition(input.begin(), input.end(), [vows](char c){return find(vows.begin(), vows.end(), c) != vows.end();});
    std::cout << " The amount of vowels found is " << std::distance(input.begin(), it_vows_end) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " The expected amount of vowels found is 2 " << std::endl;


    // If you also want to count consonants (for example if the input can also have digits or punctuation marks)
    std::vector<char> cons = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z'};
    auto it_cons_end = std::partition(it_vows_end, input.end(), [cons](char c){return find(cons.begin(), cons.end(), c) != cons.end();});
    std::cout << " The amount of consonants found is " << std::distance(it_vows_end, it_cons_end) << std::endl;

}
```

---

Output:

The input is hello
The amount of vowels found is 2
The expected amount of vowels found is 2
The amount of consonants found is 3

---

std::size_t is the return type of sizeof. So it's only natural to use it for iterating over containers. Also, as it is a standard type used by some libraries, it makes code easier to read.